# Configure cybersource payment processor using omnipay extension

Tags: payment-processor, omnipay

Has anyone configured Cybersource in civi using the omnipay extension?

The setup from https://www.ryanplugins.com/how-to-setup-cybersource-secure-acceptance-profile/ seems to add a new profile but looks like the button is missing from our test/live account

Live URL - https://ebc.cybersource.com/ebc2/.

Test URL - https://ebctest.cybersource.com/ebc2/

On `Payment Configuration` -> `Secure Acceptance Settings`, I don't see any option to create a new profile. Is this even required?

[image]

On civi side, If cybersource pp is chosen from the list at `civicrm/admin/paymentProcessor?reset=1&action=add`, we get 3 fields to be entered for completing the setup - `Profile ID`, `Access Key` and `Secret Key`

[image]